# Get values from LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How do I get the value of one of the new properties out of query in the DoIt function below?

```
public object GetData()
{
       var table = GetDataTable();
       var view = table.DefaultView;
       //..... more code
       var query = from row in view.ToTable().AsEnumerable()
                    group row by row.Field<string>("ShortName") into grouping
                    select new
                        {
                            ShortName = grouping.Key,
                            SCount = grouping.Sum( count => count.Field<int>("ProfCount")),
                            DisplayText = string.Empty
                        };
        return query;
}

// this code doesn't work
public void DoIt()
{
  var result = GetData();
  string shortName = result.ShortName;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning an anonymous type (via select new {}), which is only valid in the local scope. You need to create a concrete type and return that from your function rather than object.

```
public SomeClass GetData()
{
       var table = GetDataTable();
       var view = table.DefaultView;
       //..... more code
       var query = from row in view.ToTable().AsEnumerable()
                    group row by row.Field<string>("ShortName") into grouping
                    select new SomeClass
                        {
                            ShortName = grouping.Key,
                            SCount = grouping.Sum( count => count.Field<int>("ProfCount")),
                            DisplayText = string.Empty
                        };
        return query;
}

// this code doesn't work
public void DoIt()
{
  var result = GetData();
  string shortName = result.ShortName;
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public int SCount { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can use an existing type?  I'd rather use a datarow here.

Comment: You can absolutely use an existing type. You just can't use an anonymous type outside local scope. You just need a type that is publicly visible because you're returning it from a public method. (The explicit type could be a private nested class if the method was private.)

Comment: @James Kovacs: "You just can't use an anonymous type outside local scope." This is false (yes, there are incorrect statements on MSDN to this effect).

Comment: @Jason - Can you provide an example of using an anonymous type outside local scope without resorting to reflection?

Comment: @James:  Your comment gave me the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @James Kovacs: Yes. Can you provide a good place to share a small code snippet? I think it's unreadable in a small comment box.

Comment: @Jason - pastebin.com or gist.github.com both work well for sharing small code snippets.

Comment: @Jason - OK. That's a neat trick, but not one I'd recommend. :)

Comment: @James Kovacs: Agree. If one is doing that they might as well make an explicitly-defined type.

Answer (score 4):

Anonymous types are not called anonymous types for nothing. So:

Define a type with a name (6 additional lines of code):

```
public class Foo
{
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public int SCount { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
}
```

Now modify your `GetData` signature to (0 additional lines of code):

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> GetData()
```

And your LINQ query to (3 additional characters, or a couple more if you choose more meaningful name):

```
var query = 
    from row in view.ToTable().AsEnumerable()
    group row by row.Field<string>("ShortName") into grouping
    select new Foo
    {
        ShortName = grouping.Key,
        SCount = grouping.Sum( count => count.Field<int>("ProfCount")),
        DisplayText = string.Empty
    };
```

Comment: GetData would return an IEnumerable<Foo>, not just Foo.

Comment: @Etienne de Martel, got me. Editing :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, `DoIt` has no idea that `result` has a property named `ShortName` because its typed as an `object`. You could create a concrete class that holds the results, use reflection, or use `dynamic`. Note that either way, `GetData` is really returning an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is currently an anonymous type.

Using a concrete class:

```
public class Foo {
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public int SCount { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<Foo> GetData() {
   var table = GetDataTable();
   var view = table.DefaultView;
   //..... more code
   var query = from row in view.ToTable().AsEnumerable()
                group row by row.Field<string>("ShortName") into grouping
                select new Foo
                    {
                        ShortName = grouping.Key,
                        SCount = grouping.Sum( count => count.Field<int>("ProfCount")),
                        DisplayText = string.Empty
                    };
    return query;
}

public void DoIt() {
    var result = GetData();
    foreach(var item in result) {
        Console.WriteLine(item.ShortName);
    }
}
```

Using reflection:

```
public IEnumerable GetData() {
    var table = GetDataTable();
    var view = table.DefaultView;
    //..... more code
    var query = from row in view.ToTable().AsEnumerable()
                group row by row.Field<string>("ShortName") into grouping
                select new Foo
                    {
                        ShortName = grouping.Key,
                        SCount = grouping.Sum( count => count.Field<int>("ProfCount")),
                        DisplayText = string.Empty
                    };
    return query;
}

public void DoIt() {
    var result = GetData();
    PropertyInfo property = result.First().GetType().GetProperty("ShortName");
    foreach(var item in result) {
        string shortName = property.GetValue(item, null);
        Console.WriteLine(shortName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't without using reflection.  Since it is an anonymous type, you cannot cast to it in the `DoIt()` method either, since the type name is not known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

This gives me what I need:

```
public object GetData()
{
       var table = GetDataTable();
       var view = table.DefaultView;
       //..... more code
            var query = from row in view.ToTable().AsEnumerable()
                    group row by row.Field<string>("ShortName") into grouping
                    select new Object[]
                        {
                            grouping.Key,
                            grouping.Sum( count => count.Field<int>("ProfCount")),
                            string.Empty 
                        };
            return query;
}


public void DoIt()
{
  // Note: Pretend that GetData returned only one result
  object[] result = GetData() as object[];
  var shortName = result[0];
}
```